# Access the messages of actor mailbox

Tags: akka

I want to read the messages in ShardRegions mailbox. In previous akka version, we could use the following code to get only the size of mailbox:

```
getContext().getMailboxSize();
```

Is there any way to fetch the type of messages in the mailbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution

Define a wrapper mailbox for shard region like this:

```
class UnboundedMailboxWrapper extends MailboxType with ProducesMessageQueue[UnboundedMailboxWrapper.MessageQueue] {
  def this(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, config: Config) = this()

  final override def create(owner: Option[ActorRef], system: Option[ActorSystem]): MessageQueue =
    new UnboundedMailboxWrapper.MessageQueue
}

object UnboundedMailboxWrapper {
  class MessageQueue extends ConcurrentLinkedQueue[Envelope] with UnboundedQueueBasedMessageQueue {
    val runtime = RuntimeManager.runtime
    final def queue: Queue[Envelope] = this
    override def enqueue(receiver: ActorRef, handle: Envelope): Unit = {
      runtime.queue.add(handle)
      queue add handle
    }
    override def dequeue(): Envelope = {
      if (!runtime.queue.isEmpty) runtime.mailbox.queue.poll()
      queue.poll()
    }
  }
}
```

in this mailbox we duplicate the element which added, to another queue, so when calculate size and other operation on it, there is no any impact on performance of mailbox queue

In duplicated queue we can calculate the number of messages and sort them:

```
def getElemets(): String = {
  runtime.queue.asScala.toList.groupBy(_.message.getClass.getName)
    .map(e ⇒ (e._1, e._2.length)).toSeq
    .sortBy(_._2).foldLeft("") { (a, b) ⇒
    b._1 + ":" + b._2 + "\n" + a
  }
}
```

and with JMX or any other way we can call this method in runtime

and finlally assign this mailbox to ShardRegion dispatcher:

```
monit-dispatcher {
  mailbox-type = "im.actor.server.cluster.UnboundedMailboxWrapper"
}

akka.cluster.sharding {
  use-dispatcher = "monit-dispatcher"
}
```

Comment: Caveat: you have now completely replaced the default implementation  AbstractNodeQueue with a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue. Be aware that the default one is optimised for the actor mailbox use case and replacing it may have performance implications.

Comment: This is the implementation of akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox and I've just copied it. The akka implementation of UnboundedMailbox uses ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Comment: Yes, you are right, not sure why I was thinking of the abstract node queue (it's used in the scheduler). That `there is no any impact on performance` is probably not correct though, you are duplicating the work being done and the storage overhead with the extra queue, plus that the extra queue must be polled somewhere else or the elements are kept in memory for ever, even if they were passed on to the actor.

Comment: What do you mean *elements kept in memory forever* ? We polled the elements in dequeue and this method will be called when message passed to the actor. 
Calculating the size of the queue have costs and we suffer a little memory overhead to reduce these cost